# Distance between triangle's centroid and incenter, given coordinates of vertices

Tags: geometry

> If $G$ is the centroid and $I$ is the in-center of the triangle, with vertices $A(-36,7)$, $B(20,7)$, and $C(0,-8)$, then find the length of $GI$.

Well the obvious way to approach this problem would be to centroid of the triangle and then the incenter of the triangle, and then find the distance. Is there an easier method to do this problem? Doing it that way would get a bit lengthy.

Comment: I removed the `graph-theory` tag, since graph theory is an entirely different field of mathematics. :)

Comment: The sides of the triangle can be immediately calculated. After that, the coordinates of $G$ are just the averages of the coordinates of the vertices. For the incenter the formula is simple: you can find it here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Incenter.html In my opinion there's no simpler way.

Comment: As @BeniBogosel notes, the centroid and incenter have straightforward coordinate formulas (average and weighted-average, respectively). It occurs to me that these imply that the vector from centroid to incenter has its own interesting form:
$$\overrightarrow{GI} =\frac{(b-a)(B-A)+(c-b)(C-B)+(a-c)(A-C)}{3(a+b+c)}$$ (where, of course, $a$, $b$, $c$ are the lengths of the sides opposite respective vertices $A$, $B$, $C$).

Comment: @Blue How exactly can you subtract coordinate points?

Comment: @Gummybears: You'll see this all the time when you learn about vectors. Until then, think of it as shorthand: we add (subtract) points by adding (subtracting) their corresponding coordinates; we multiply (divide) a point by a number by multiplying (dividing) each coordinate by that number. So, for instance, with $A(x,y)$ and $B(u,v)$, we have $$A+B = (x+u, y+v)\quad\text{and}\quad 2 A = (2 x, 2 y )$$ and even $$2 A + 5 B = ( 2 x + 5 u, 2 y + 5 v )$$ This lets us write things like $$G = \frac{1}{3}(A+B+C)$$ more compactly than as $$G = \left(\frac{A_x+B_x+C_x}{3}, \frac{A_y+B_y+C_y}{3}\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

The side lengths are $a=25,b=39,c=56$ by the pythagorean theorem and the area is $\Delta=420$ by the Heron's formula or the shoelace formula, hence $r=7$. Since $h_c=\frac{2\Delta}{c}$, the length of the height relative to $C$ is $15$, hence the distance of $G$ from $AB$ is just $5$.

It is well known that $I=\frac{aA+bB+cC}{a+b+c}$ and $AI^2=bc-4rR=bc-\frac{2abc}{a+b+c}$, hence $IG^2$ can also be computed through the [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem). Let we assume that $A$ has mass $a$, $B$ has mass $b$ and $C$ has mass $c$. With such assumptions, $I$ is the center of mass of $S=\{A,B,C\}$ and the moment of inertia of $S$ around $I$ is given by:
$$ M_I = a AI^2 + b BI^2 + c CI^2 = 3abc - 4(a+b+c) rR = abc $$
while the moment of inertia of $S$ around $G$ is given by:
$$ M_G = a AG^2 + b BG^2 + c CG^2 = \frac{1}{9}\sum_{cyc}a(2b^2+2c^2-a^2) $$
and by the parallel axis theorem $ M_G = (a+b+c) IG^2 + M_I$, hence:

> $$ IG^2 = \frac{M_G-M_I}{a+b+c} = \boxed{\frac{\frac{2}{3}(a+b+c)^3-\frac{5}{3}(a^3+b^3+c^3)-13abc}{9(a+b+c)}}.$$

---

A difficult problem has just born:
 Prove that if $a,b,c$ are the side lengths of a triangle,
 $$ 2(a+b+c)^3 \geq 5 (a^3+b^3+c^3) + 39abc. $$

Tricky solution: $IG^2\geq 0$, and equality is achieved only when $I\equiv G$, i.e. when $a=b=c$.